# In which part of the code should I check for undefined

Tags: angular, typescript

There is a method

```
product$!: Observable<Product>;

  getProduct(): void {
    this.product$ = this.route.params
      .pipe( switchMap( params => {
        return this.productServ.getById(params['id'])
      }))
  }
```

which returns, an object of type

```
export interface Product {
  type?: string
  id?: string
  title?: string
  date?: Date | undefined;
}
```

and a template that displays the properties of this object

```
<div *ngIf="product$ | async as product; else loading">
  <h2>{{ product.title}}</h2>
```

As a result of calling the (getProduct) method, the variable this.product$ may be undefined.
Therefore, IDEA throws an error in this line of the template

```
<h2>{{ product.title}}</h2>
```

How is this problem solved correctly

- in the template, add a check *gif="product.title"
- or this problem should be solved in the code, then the question is how to do it correctly

Answer (score 1):

Did you try `*ngIf="(product$ | async) as product; else loading"`?

Also you can define an empty observable as `product$ = Observable.of<Product>(Product())` before rendering